# Rails concurrent background processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, resque, spawn

I need to access and pull data from a number of API's over the the course of the a number of days. This is streaming data so the process will be running all the time. Each process will pulling in data and inserting it into a separate google fusion table.

As I want to run this processes in the background and forget about them, just being able to monitor is they fail and don't restart.

I have looked at Delayed Job, Resque, Beanstalk etc and my question is can these run processes concurrently. I don't want to queue processes just run them in the background.

I looked at Spawn as well, but didn't completely understand how it worked.

So what options are available to me, does anybody does have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule cron jobs to pull data.

```
every 2.hours do 
  YourApi.do_whatever
  SecondApi.do_the_thing
end
```

Comment: These processes have to be persistent and run constantly in order to capture the data from the streaming api over a number of days. Thats why i didn't think a scheduling gem/script/app like cron or something would work for me. I open to being corrected though

Comment: Ahh, then look at God to make sure your proc is running

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a custom background daemon is a better fit you, take a look at [daemon_generator](https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator). But note that you probably have to do some work if you want to do things concurrently but just processing things in serial should be quite easy.